# Dynamically rearranging elements in a specific order?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a handful of div's, like so...

```
<div id="topDiv"></div>
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
<div id="D"></div>
```

On button click, I'd like to call a function that arranges these div's in a specific order, with the "topDiv" always staying at the top. The argument that is passed to the function specifies the order that the div's should be arranged in...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        reorderListItems("#C, #A, #D, #B");
    });
}); 


function reorderListItems(items) {
    $(items).insertAfter("#topDiv"); 
}
```

So when this function is called, I'd like the div's to appear in this order --> topDiv, C, A, D, B.

I realize that I cannot use the "items" string this way for the "insertAfter" selector. So would anyone know what I would need to change to make this work? Or might there be a different (better) way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/KUWUd/

This would work:

```
function reorderListItems(items) {

 //split() returns an array
  var itemArray = items.split(","); //split the original item string into individual strings
  var target = $('#topDiv'); //original target
  for (var i=0; i<itemArray.length; i++) {
   var item = itemArray[i];  
   $(item).insertAfter(target); //select each ID and insert
   target = $(item); //update target
  }
}
```

You were passing the original string to the `reOrderListItems()`  function and you used that argument as a selector argument for `$`. That would not work. The string argument needs to be split into constituent characters and those characters used as arguments to `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way, you had the right idea. Just make the sort function do what you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebytG/)

```
var sortOrder = ["C", "A", "D", "B"];
$('button').click(function () {
    //Select all divs following #topDiv
    var sorted = $('#topDiv ~ div').get().sort(reorderListItems)
    $(sorted).insertAfter('#topDiv');
});

function reorderListItems(a, b) {
    return sortOrder.indexOf(a.id) > sortOrder.indexOf(b.id)
}
```

`sortOrder` needs to contain the exact IDs of the divs for this to work as it is.

Comment: LD... much thanks for the alternate method, it appears to work just as well! :) Wish I could "accept" multiple answers!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to come up with a solution with the least overhead since you're using jQuery. I can probably get you one that doesn't use jQuery at all, if that'll sway you, haha.